# WP - Extend main query with custom meta query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a theme that supports posts with multiple authors. I keep the co-authors IDs in post meta. The problem is that on author archive page I need to show not only posts by the author, but also the posts he is co-author and they need to be in the same loop. 
So here is my question: is there a good way extend the main query with custom one ( while still retain paging, etc ).

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($query) {
 if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query()) return;

 if ($query->is_archive() && $query->is_author()) {

 $author_id = get_query_var('author');

 // extend the main query with these post ids
 $coauthored_posts = get_posts([
 'fields'         => 'ids',
 'posts_per_page' => '-1',
 'post_status'    => 'publish',
 'meta_query' => [
        [
 'key' => 'co_authors',
 'value' => $author_id,
 'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        ]
      ]
    ]);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the result of your Query? Did you try with the 'IN' operator for 'compare' in your meta_query?

Comment: The result is as it should be - giving me array of ids of posts, to which the author is listed as co-author. The problem is merging the these posts with the main query and have the paging in place.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine meta_query:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'author',
        'value' => $author_id,
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'co_authors',
        'value'   => $co_author_id,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($query) {
    if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query()) return;
    if ($query->is_archive() && $query->is_author()) {

        $author_id = get_query_var('author');

        // extend the main query with these post ids
        $cauthored_arg = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'orderby '=>'ID'
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'co_authors',
                    'value'   => $author_id,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
            )
        );  

        $coauthored_posts = new WP_Query( $cauthored_arg );
    }
});
```